# How can I print values in a loop?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, cout

In my code, all values are not printed in sequence.

Only the first value will be printed.

But I want to print the values in the order of the variable ***in***.

***in*** is a variable that takes the number of products.

```
   for(j=0;j<in;j++){
         cout<<"Id: "<<p1[j].id<<"\t Name: "<<p1[j].name<<endl;
   }
```

Comment: If that code is printing only one value, then it's because the `in` variable has a value of one.

Comment: your code should output the products for indices 0 to `in-1`. Is this not working?
What do you mean, then, by `in sequence` or `order of in`? Do you want to have sorted output? If sorted, by what, by `p1[...].id`?

Comment: Really to get help with a bug in your progam you need to show more than three lines of code. The error is your program is not in the code you have posted, the error is somewhere in the code you haven't posted. Until you post the code with the error it''s going to be hard to help you.

Comment: Edit the question to include more code, in particular code affecting `in` and `p1`. Also *quote* (don't describe) the actual input and the expected output. It's much easier to understand when people show what they want instead of trying to describe what they want.

Comment: PLease read this: [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

You can use ostream::write .
This accepts a character array and the size of the array . 
The array is copied directly to the streambuffer.

Example:

```
char array[8];
//fill in array

//Because std::cout is an ostream
std::cout.write( array, 8 )
```